# Referencing a merged resource dictionary in windows phone seven failing

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, mvvm-light, resourcedictionary

I am currently building a WP7 app using the MVVMLight framework. I would like to add a resource dictionary to my app.xaml, however when I do it fails. Here is a snipit from the app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!--Global View Model Locator-->
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                         d:IsDataSource="True" />
    <!--Merged Resource Dictionaries-->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="View/StyleResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Because I am using a ViewModelLocator that has a key, I get an error warning me that I can not mix resources with and without keys. After adding a key to my resource dictionary It looks like the following:

```
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="resourceDictionary">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="View/StyleResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

In the resource dictionary I have a style with the key "TitleTemplate". In either case when I try to reference the resource dictionary from one of my views it fails. Sample code from my view is bellow:

```
<TextBlock Name="TB_ContactNameLabel" 
           Text="contact" 
           Style="{StaticResource TitleTemplate}"/>
```

The designer immediately gives me the error "The resource 'TitleTemplate' could not be resolved". If I reference the key of the resourced dictionary (ie: resourceDictionary) no error is thrown but it doesn't do anything obviously. Finally if I add the resourceDictionary directly to the page in its resources, instead of the app.xaml everything works fine. I do not want to have to add it to each view I plan to use. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your application resources should look like the following:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!--Global View Model Locator-->
    <!--Merged Resource Dictionaries-->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="View/StyleResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked perfectly. But can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: @ferics2: If using a merged dictionary, the resource dictionary has to be the single root of the Resources property definition, and all resources have to be defined within it.  That's just the way it works.

Comment: Thanks @Will. Yeah, when adding another dictionary to an existing one (merging) then other resources need to be put into the dictionary.