# "Unable to determine application identity of the caller" for ViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

In app.xaml, i have an error while defining ViewModelLocator. App launches and runs fine, but it annoys me in Studio. Wondering, what can be a reason. Highlighted line is

```
<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
```

Error:

> Error 1   Unable to determine application identity of the caller.

If to get inside of vm:ViewModelLocator, there's no sign of errors there. Should i re-check all my viewmodels and add IsoStorage designtime protection?

```
if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
{
    settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has the same issue. Just recommendation: try to open your project in Blend and attach VS to it. You'll immediately see, where problem is (usually, it is about accessing IsoStorage during designtime).

EDIT: to be more accurate, adding DesignMode check solves my problem with highlighting.

```
public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            return;

    ****
```

Comment: What do you mean attach VS to it?

Comment: Debug/Attach to Process/Blend - in that way, you'd be able to debug your code, while running from Blend.

Comment: Also, this article can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886698/referencing-a-merged-resource-dictionary-in-windows-phone-seven-failing

Comment: Ok, I will check that out but I tired to attach to blend and when the error message comes up, nothing gets triggered in VS even though I am getting the error message.

Comment: I am not sure the article you linked to applies, I just get that error message as a dialog message box. I would like to hunt it down and correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574574/unable-to-determine-application-identity-call-how-to-track-down