# Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key in windows phone 8 project

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I created a new **Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight) project**.
Added **Themes** folder, added two resource dictionaries to this folder, one containing *solidcolorbursh* and one containing *colors*.

I merged these two resource dictionaries in App.xaml

In MainPage.xaml I used one solidcolorbursh to background of grid.

**CODE SNIPPETS:**

**App.xaml:**

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="mainStyle">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/resTest;component/Themes/MyColors.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>    
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/resTest;component/Themes/MyStyles.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:resTest" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>    
        </ResourceDictionary>           
    </Application.Resources>
```

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource RedSolidColorBrush}">
</Grid>
```

**MyColors.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Color x:Key="RedColor">#FFFF0000</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MyStyles.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RedSolidColorBrush" Color="{StaticResource RedColor}"></SolidColorBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Exception thrown:

> Blockquote
>
> 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in System.Windows.ni.dll
> Its showing runtime error:
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in
> System.Windows.ni.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key
> RedColor [Line: 14 Position: 44]

Where am I wrong?

**References**:
*https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903952(VS.95).aspx*

*https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2010/09/24/consuming-resources-from-external-assemblies-in-silverlight-4/*

*[Referencing a merged resource dictionary in windows phone seven failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886698/referencing-a-merged-resource-dictionary-in-windows-phone-seven-failing)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to see `MyColors.xaml` from `MyStyles.xaml` otherwise it won't be able to find the definition of `RedColor`.

If you include the following in `MyStyles.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="...";component/MyColors.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

where "..." is the path to `MyColors.xaml`, then you should be able to refer to the colours defined therein.

Though merging the dictionaries in `App.xaml` as you already have done should produce the same effect. If you do change `MyStyles.xaml` to include `MyColors.xaml` you should remove the reference to `MyColors.xaml` from `App.xaml`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
If the build action of the ResourceDictionary  file is set to Resource you can reference it in this way:

```
/<assembly name>;component/<resource file path>
```

If the build action is set to Content then you can reference it in this way:

```
/<resource file path>
```

Then:
We need to merge MyColors in MyStyles.
Thankyou @ChrisF

Actually I am used to code for Windows Phone 8.1 or UWP, which doesn't have these issues.